# how to use c++11 move semantics to explicitly avoid copying

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a line in which a structure-typed variable is repeatedly used only in one computation, whose result is assigned back to the variable itself.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        e = f(i,e); //how to avoid copying
```

The entire code is listed below. My question is,

how to explicitly make sure that the data inside `e` is not copied many times over.

Is move semantics a good option?

How does using move compare to defining `e` as a plain non-constant reference?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct arr {
   vector<int> data;
   int len;
};

arr f(int x,arr xs) { 
   xs.data.push_back(x);
   return xs;
}

arr g() {
    arr e;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        e = f(i,e); //how to avoid copying
    return e;
}
int main() { 
    auto res = g(); return 0;
}
```

--- EDIT ---

The closest to what I am looking for is in the comment about changing to `e = f(i,std::move(e))`. From what I understand, it tells the compiler explicitly that (the second occurrence of) `e` is no longer needed and its resources can be taken, which I guess is something compiler cannot infer and must be told.

The reason I wrote the example code this way is that I want to avoid the use non-const reference in a `void f` and get the good-looks/illusion of non-side effect code without sacrificing efficiency. I think that's one thing that the move semantics buys us, right? (allowing standard containers to be 'copied' arround). I faked the `len` field and the `struct` to make a case because stl containers already have all the move semantic handlers.

Given what I learned so far from the answers, my question really boils down to this:
Before and after I use `e = f(i,std::move(e))` in the code, how many `vector` copy operations really happened? Is it none or 100? And why?

Do I need to declare `f` as `arr f(int x,arr&& xs) {`, and why or why not do I need to use `&&`?

Comment: Why not pass arr to f by reference instead ?

Comment: `e = f(i, std::move(e));`

Answer (score 3):

> how to explicitly make sure that the data inside e is not copied many times over.

Pass arr by reference.

> Is move semantics a good option?

It is not a good option in this case. You assign the result back to e (so it would work). The problem is if you do something in f that would cause a failure (throw an exception). In this case, not only do you lose the changes, but all of `e` (because it's value would be moved into `f` but not assigned back).

> How does using move compare to defining e as a plain non-constant reference?

Using move means you make an efficient, destructive copy (the original is left empty after the operation).

Comment: but wont f() return e by move back to loop?

Comment: also OP cannot "Pass arr by const reference." because it is modified in f

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you can use pointer or reference

Answer (score 0):

> how to explicitly make sure that the data inside e is not copied many
>   times over.
>
> Is move semantics a good option?

No, at least not in this case. You need to take the array by reference:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct arr {
   vector<int> data;
   int len;
};

void f(arr& a, int x) {
  a.data.push_back(x); 
}

arr g() {
    arr e;
    e.data.reserve(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        f(e, i);
    return e;
}

int main() { 
    auto res = g(); return 0;
}
```

If you know the number of elements (`100` in your example), you might want to reserve space for them, it is more efficient that way.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary to utnapistim's answer, I offer you an alternative you can write that achieves the same result, i.e. filling a vector with n consecutive integer values with C++11 language and library features.

Given the fact that you obviously want to group a `vector` and an `int` which seems to be intended to store the size of the array, the shortest possible version I can come up with and which is

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct arr {
  std::vector<int> data;
  int len;
};

int main() {
  arr a;
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(a.data), 100, [&]() -> int { return a.data.size (); });
  return 0;
}
```

There is no way around the construct of `arr::data`. Assuming you can't estimate the number of elements that's going to be pushed, resizing it before pushing isn't an option as well. Still, you can have `generate_n` simply `push_back` (through the use of `std::back_inserter`) n values that are generated by a generator function (which, as you can see, can be a neat little lambda). Effectively, you can reduce your code and your problems significantly.

The above solution avoids multiple problems of your original code:

a) You don't have to call the unnecessary function `f()` - it merely does a `push_back`, something you could just have written in `g()` directly. Defining and calling `f()` is just completely unnecessary, but the worst part is that you copy `arr` *every time* you want to push_back a single integer. That means you have to construct a new `vector` every time *and* copy whatever resided in the original, meaning n constructions of whatever type you store in your vector.

b) You don't have to write an explicit loop and call `push_back` manually. This makes function `g()` unnecessary.

c) Finally and subsequently, you avoid the function call to `g()`. Initializing `res` with the return value of `g()` is usually not a problem because of return-value optimization which eliminates the need to copy the local `vector` in `g()` (and that's exactly what `g++` does when calling `g()` to initialize `res`). However, this is more of a code reduction than a performance optimization - you have one less function to write and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Per qwm's comment on the question, using

```
e = f(i,std::move(e));
```

would save you one copy, while two more expected copies are actually moves.

- passing argument by copy
- returning by copy (actually move constructor)
- assigning back to your object (actually move assignment)

There is also a move for returning from g.

But as the other answers stated, use pass-by-reference instead. Or use the vector directly instead of a struct (vectors know their own length).

By the way, if you know beforehand how many elements your vector will hold, just set the size of the vector and use a loop to assign the elements like you would an array. Using push_back has overhead due to capacity checks at every call.